# How can I convert a Survival mode save back to a normal save?

Tags: fallout-4

Without thinking when I launched the game, the first thing I did was change the difficulty on one of my main saves to Survival mode.  After playing through Survival mode and realizing how tough it was (especially since I hadn't finished exploring the entire Commonwealth), I tried switching back but found no option to do so.

Apparently, from looking online, the changes I make are "final" if I decide to convert a save from normal to Survival. But I made these changes on accident fully unaware of the repercussions of doing so.

If I want to convert a Survival mode save back to a normal mode or playthrough, is there a way to tweak the save to change it back to normal mode?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Survival mode is available **publicly** if you opt-in to the beta on Steam. I see no reason to close this question.

Comment: [Public beta content is on topic per meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available)

Comment: Are you playing the beta survival mode or the one that came with the game at release? Unfortunately you need to specify, since we decided that patch beta was on-topic. Wish we hadn't done that. A beta game is one thing, but a beta patch where alternate content is already released is quite confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can switch a survival game to a different difficulty the same way you normally change the difficulty, through the `Settings` -> `Gameplay` menu. I don't know if this was missing when the beta was released yesterday, but I just tested it by loading a save, switching it to survival, and then switching it back.

Lowering the difficulty from survival is a one-way change, you cannot lower the difficulty and then raise it back to survival, as indicated by the warning you get when you try to lower the difficulty:

[image]