# How do you get to locations only accessible by fast travel in the new Survival Mode?

Tags: fallout-4

Survival Mode in Fallout 4 is being revamped, according to [a Bethesda tweet](https://twitter.com/BethesdaStudios/status/697886212640665600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw). A [subsequent post on Bethesda's website](https://bethesda.net/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=032916-FO4-survival&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=032916-FO4-Survival#en/events/game/fallout-4s-all-new-survival-mode/2016/03/29/96) details all of the changes that will be implemented for players on the Survival difficulty.

As of 03/29/16, this [update is available as beta on Steam](http://www.polygon.com/2016/3/29/11324302/fallout-4-survival-mode-beta-steam-details).

One of the features for this updated Survival Mode, per the Bethesda post, states that fast traveling is disabled. However, there is at least one location that seem to only be accessible by fast traveling.

> The Institute, after they install the relay into your Pip-Boy as part of the [Institutionalized](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Institutionalized) quest.

How do you visit locations that are only accessible by fast traveling while playing in the updated Survival Mode?

Comment: To whomever voted to close: According to the comments in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260674/how-can-i-convert-a-survival-mode-save-back-to-a-normal-save), as well as the linked Meta conversation, [public beta content is on topic](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available). The new survival mode beta [was released on Steam today](http://www.polygon.com/2016/3/29/11324302/fallout-4-survival-mode-beta-steam-details).

Comment: That's me. I saw that article afterward. I still think it's important to make it clear that you're asking about the beta survival mode, as there is an existing survival mode which conflicts. You've sort of done with with "the updated Survival Mode". I also had to waste a few minutes on the first of these questions trying to figure out why they were asking about something unreleased, so some clarification would be good.

Comment: The Prydwen is accessible via Vertibird from the Boston Airport. I assume this is still the case in the new mode.

Comment: @DCShannon I've played this game so much... and had absolutely **no** idea that there was a Vertibird transport at the Boston Airport. Wow. I'll update my question on that one, then. Thanks. I'll also try to make it more clear I'm talking about the survival mode updates that Bethesda announced a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: That seems much better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can teleport into to the Institute from any exterior location in survival mode but you cannot teleport out to any location. You will basically be asked to teleport to the CIT ruins. On the case of faction usefulness for fast travel in survival mode, the Brotherhood is a lot better with the vertibird as they can travel from anywhere to anywhere just take a while to get there as its a physical form of transport (still way faster than on foot and safer).

Hope this helps you .

Comment: I'm up to this point in my survival playthrough, and this is indeed the case. You can get mods to change this behavior on PC and Xbox, probably PS4 as well. The one on Xbox is currently the Survival Options mod, which lets you set other options as well. The Vertibirds are better most of the time, but it takes a while for the bird to arrive, whereas the teleport is instant and takes you to a store. You can always call a vertibird from CIT.